# Add Google Mobile Vision library dependency to gradle

Tags: android, google-vision

i want to add google mobile vision library by add this line to build.gradle :

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.6.0'

but android studio error!

what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using different lib version. This works perfectly for me

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
```